Using Value from Another Function in Pandas .Applymap()
Is it possible to color code DataFrame cell values based on its value compared to the value returned from another function.
Here is an example of the DataFrame coloring that I created using the functions below. Dateframe Coloring](https://i.sstatic.net/iVhJeJdj.png)
For example:
I have a function that takes one argument, a contract value, and returns a tuple.
def net_60_comp(amount,f_rate=0.043):
    dis_to_60 = amount * ((1+f_rate)**(60/365)-1)
    dis_perc_to_60 = dis_to_60/amount

    return(dis_to_60,dis_perc_to_60)

Could the value, "dis_to_60", returned from my above function be used in the color function below to determine color coding rather than using a hardcoded value?
def color (val):
    v = net_60_comp
    color = 'green' if int(val) > 80 else 'red'
    return f'background-color: {color}'


df.style.applymap(color)


you can create def color(val, other_value) and use applymap(lambda x:color(x, dis_to_60))

You can create
def color(val, other_value):

and use lambda to run it with other_value
dis_to_60, dis_perc_to_60 = net_60_comp(...)

.applymap(lambda x:color(x, dis_to_60))


Documentation suggests that you can also use
.applymap(color, other_value=dis_to_60)


I tried this and this appeared to work. Thanks!

if it helped then you can mark my answer as accepted, and some time later you can upvote it.
